# Should I use PrevTaskStatus vs TaskStatus when sessions are disabled

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to understand when to use PrevTaskStatus vs TaskStatus when defining link conditions in Informatica.  I understand PrevTaskStatus takes into account the last task executed by the integration service, ignoring disabled tasks.

But if that is the case, then does PrevTaskStatus return the same value for ALL session objects.

i.e. doesnt $session1.PrevTaskStatus, $session20.PrevTaskStatus both equal SUCCEEDED if session 10 has just completed successfully.

or is $session20.PrevTaskStatus somehow referring to the last task executed PRIOR to $session20, and $session30.PrevTaskStatus somehow refer to a different session.

If I have:

session1 --> session2 --> session3 --> session4

and session 3 is disabled

and I want to put in a link condition from session3 to session4

do I use:

```
$Start.PrevTaskStatus = SUCCEEDED
$session3.PrevTaskStatus = SUCCEEDED
$session4.PrevTaskStatus = SUCCEEDED
```

Thanks